# File naming for MultiResourceItemWriter to use a prefix instead of a suffix

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using MultiResourceItemWriter to write to multiple files and I want to customize the file names. Instead of suffix, I want the prefix to increment.

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemWriter<MyEntity> customMultiResourceItemWriter() {
    MultiResourceItemWriter<MyEntity> writer = new MultiResourceItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("output.txt"));
    writer.setResourceSuffixCreator(index -> "_" + index);
    writer.setDelegate(flatFileItemWriter());

    return writer;
}
```

Is there a way to customize the file name?